# How to say you had extra time?

Tags: word-choice, idioms

Yesterday I had an exam and I didn't spend the last 25 minutes of exam time (I finished before the deadline). I thought how to say this in English. It should be something like

> I got ... time

or

> I got 25 minutes ...

I also appreciate if someone answer with idioms or slangs.

Comment: I'd usually say, *I finished [25 minutes] early* or *I finished with 25 minutes to spare*.  Or maybe "*I turned in my test with 25 minutes to go.*" If you want to be a smart-aleck you could even say, "*They made that test 25 minutes longer than they needed to.*"

Comment: Jim, you made some good suggestions. You should post them as an answer.

Answer (score 3):

I think the proper way to say this is:

> *I had 25 minutes of time to spare*.

Use of idioms is not really required in such a simple sentence. As such I am not really qualified to give that. On the other hand, I do not really know if slangs are the way to go here. When learning English, it is best that you adhere to the dialect that is prevalent in your part of the world.

For example, here in India, where I am from, it is common to say

> *I had....*

Meanwhile, in the US, it is common to say

> *I got....*

Usage of proper dialect is more important than colloquialism.

Comment: A couple points... (1) No need to say _of time_; "I had 25 minutes to spare" says it just fine – "of time" is superfluous. (2) The equivalent to the informal "I got" is "I **have**", not "I had". "I got" is used in the present tense, as in, _"Do you want to go to lunch? Or do I need to get you to the airport?"_ Answer: _"Let's go to lunch, I got 25 minutes to spare."_ In the past tense, though, I would always use "had", and never "got": _"My friend took me to lunch, because I **had** 25 minutes to spare."_ (3) I'm not sure _proper dialect_ is ALWAYS more important than _colloquialism_. Hmmmm.

Comment: *"I got 25 minutes of time to spare."???*  As an American, that sounds totally wrong.  In the past tense, it should be either *"I had",  "I had got",* or *"I'd got".* In other words, *"I've got"* can be shortened to *"I got"*, but *"I'd got"* cannot.

Comment: @Peter: I've heard it used; in that context, the word "got" is often pronounced as "gut", as in, "Do have a minute?" _"Yeah, I gut a minute, whatchu need?"_ You're right, it's a shortening of "I've got".

Comment: @J.R. That corresponds to present tense ("I have a moment"), not past tense ("I had a moment). I see my comment is ambiguous. I meant "I got 25 minutes to spare" sounds wrong in the answer's context.

Comment: @J.R. : I'm sure my limited exposure to American English is putting me at a disadvantage here. So I apologize for any mistakes. However, I do stand by the statement that proper dialect is more important than colloquialism. For example, in India, where I'm from, I would have said, *"It is a number one quality product"* instead of saying *"It is a quality product"*. Similarly, as the original question also included idioms and slangs for this usage, I provided an opinion depending on my own experience with local and international differences.

Comment: Then again, I do acknowledge that @J.R. is correct in pointing out the use of **got** and **had**. I was also reminded of a common usage to the original post. Correct me if I'm wrong, but I believe one can also say, ***I finished 25 minutes before time.***

Comment: I didn't disagree with your statement about dialects and colloquialisms. I simply thought it was quite interesting, and I wanted to think about it some more. I was running out of characters, though, so I summarized all that with "Hmmmm." I'm glad you elaborated.

Comment: I've never heard of a summary with "Hmmmm". (*Hahahaha*) I hope I am accurate, to a certain degree, about the dialect thing. It is one of the reasons that has always made English such a delight to study.

Comment: I don't think anyone anywhere would say “I got 25 minutes to spare” in this context. It _would_ be said in some places to indicate a _present state,_ just not a past event like the one in question (probably because it would sound like one was colloquially describing a present state).

Answer (score 2):

English speakers will often refer to time as spent or wasted, along the lines of [*time-based currency*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time-based_currency).

If I’m interpreting your question correctly, the idiomatic phrase you’re seeking is:

> I got 25 minutes of my life back.

or

> I had 25 minutes to do whatever I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

> I had 25 minutes left of the available exam time when I left.